# Change display of multiple classes on psuedo class hover

Tags: css, sass

This is my scss file

```
  .image-container {
    position: relative;
    .delete-image {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
    }
    .make-primary {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 97px;
    }
    &:hover .delete-image {
      display: block;
      }
  }
```

I want both `.make-primary` and `.delete-image` to have their `display` attribute be changed to block on hover.

I tried:

```
&:hover .delete-image .make-primary{
          display: block;
          }
```

and

```
&:hover .delete-image, .make-primary {
          display: block;
          }
```

The first one, shows neither element, and the second will show `.delete-image` on hover and the `.make-primary` is always shown.  Neither of these are showing the .make-primary element on hover.
What is the correct syntax?  Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not describe the problem.  Did you even look at the compiled results?  It should be pretty obvious how this should work.

Comment: @cinnamon How do I view the compiled results?  SOrry for my noobiness.

Comment: You don't know how to open the resulting CSS file?

Comment: This is part of a rails app. I can view the css of the web page in the console, but I can't figure out my problem with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put both of the class selectors inside the `&:hover`:

```
&:hover{
    .delete-image, .make-primary {
        display: block;
     }
}
```

That will compile to [this](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9ae28d88a330c0cb9690)

Or add `&:hover` in front of the second class:

```
&:hover .delete-image, &:hover .make-primary {
   display: block;
}
```

With the [same output](http://sassmeister.com/gist/2bd4280006097c7c8dce).